# Convert inner advance for loops to check for null

Tags: java, for-loop, set

I have something like this

```
Set<String> scene = myClass.getScene();
Set<String> time = myClass.getTime();
Set<String> possibleKey= new HashSet<String>();
for(String selectedTime: time){
   for(String Selectedscene: scene) {
      String key = selectedTime+selectedScene;
      possibleKey.add(key)
    }
 }
```

This code is under assumption that scene and time will never be null. Now, I need to convert it such that any or both of the parameters(scene or time) can be null. So if time is null, the key should be generated with scene and if scene is null, the key should be generated with time.

Please help. I am confused here.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly; could you share some more code? For example, `String key = time+scene;` doesn't make sense when `time` and `scene` are `Set`s of strings.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case you can achieve the result you want by using a set with a single empty string in place of a `null` set:

```
Set<String> single = new HashSet<String>();
single.add("");
if (time == null) {
     time = single;
}
if (scene == null) {
     scene = single;
}
```

This would work as long as you concatenate `selectedTime` and `selectedScene` with no delimiters in between them.

Comment: What if the scene and time sets contain a null element? That's what the OP seems to be concerned about.

Comment: Is it possible to make it generic to handle other elements(for key generation) in future? I mean what if in future I have one more element added apart from time and scene?

Comment: @CKing OP is very specific in his question about what can be `null` - it's `time` and `scene`, not their elements.

Comment: @Viksraj This would not work generically, but in your specific case you can get by with a single-element solution.